# Using 'requests' module for POST, I want to pick up entire JSON body from whole csv cells/values

Tags: python, json, csv, google-sheets, automated-tests

I've been trying to write a little python script to automate some API testing.

I need it to pick up the whole JSON body from a CSV or other format file, but not just a single body per file, rather iterate over all the "bodies" in it.

The way I concocted it is, each cell, or value, is an entire body. This comes from how I'm managing various tests in Google Sheets, with the whole JSON bodies in their own cells, and can then be easily exported as CSV files.

The issue is that I keep hitting "wrong format" type errors. I think the problem is that, as it's picking it up as a CSV "value", it inputs the data weirdly and that's why it won't work.

**Sample "problematic" input**, i.e. the value that is picked up from the CSV file, as caught through a breakpoint:

```
'{"post":2027,"name":"Test User","email":"email@mail.com","body":"lorem ipsum4"}'
```

I've already tried a lot of things. This is where I'm at right now. Further below is some sample data and more explanations.

**Code:**

```
from os import read
import requests
import csv
import json

filename = 'file.csv'

url = "https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/posts/[id]/comments"

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer tricked ya"
}

with open(filename) as cF: 
    reader = csv.reader(cF)
    for idx,row in enumerate(reader):
        for col in row:
            print("Body: ", col)
            r = requests.request("POST", url, headers = headers, json = col)
            print("Status: ", r.status_code)
            print("Status: ", r.reason)
            print("Text response: ", r.text)
            print("\nTest number: ",idx,"\n")
```

Sample data. In here, each row is a row in a csv file:

```
{"post":2027,"name":"Test User","email":"email@mail.com","body":"lorem ipsum1"}
{"post":2027,"name":"Test User","email":"email@mail.com","body":"lorem ipsum2"}
{"post":2027,"name":"Test User","email":"email@mail.com","body":"lorem ipsum3"}
{"post":2027,"name":"Test User","email":"email@mail.com","body":"lorem ipsum4"}
```

Sample output: ("Text response" slightly post-formatted for readability)

```
Body:  {"post":2027,"name":"Test User","email":"email@mail.com","body":"lorem ipsum4"}
Status:  422
Status:  Unprocessable Entity
Text response:  
{
    "meta": null,
    "data": [{
        "field": "name",
        "message": "can't be blank"
    }, {
        "field": "email",
        "message": "can't be blank"
    }, {
        "field": "body",
        "message": "can't be blank"
    }]
}

Test number:  4
```

The "odd" thing I've noticed, is that I can sometimes (in previous versions) input the body that is printed out (such as in the sample output) back into the JSON, when I'm using breakpoints, and that will work perfectly. So I tried using something to "capture" that "working printed body", but that wasn't really doable, or I didn't do it right.

Comment: Might be useful to see (anonymized)  the url and headers you are posting. Separately, did you know google provides a python package for reading/writing sheets to simplify having to use low level requests? https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

Comment: I've now added the entire code, as I had already made some edit with the intent of presenting it but I thought it would be too much at first. Still, the code I added won't work as each ID is personal and such, but it's an open/free testing API.

And, I did not know about that google package! Thank you.

Comment: The message in the response says that a `post` field must exist, there is no such field in the sample strings you have provided: `{"name":"lorem", "email":"ipsum", "body":"lorem ipsum1"}`

Comment: You're right. I messed up the body straight from the source in this instance. I'll fix it up and re-edit it.

Comment: I've corrected the input data now, but it still won't work. Doing the requests with the exact same body, on Postman or Go Rest's own tool, actually do work. I'll look into Google's Python module after work, see if that makes it better.

Comment: "back into the JSON" Back into *what* JSON? Also, the way you're using that not-actually CSV file, `col` would be `{"post":2027`.

Comment: Do you want `for idx, row in enumerate(cF):` `print("Body: ", row)` instead?

Comment: @khvc I tried running it locally and got Status:  401 Unauthorized. is there a way to recreate the scenario you suggested above?

Comment: With "back into the JSON" I mean that I take the printed _body_ value (which I've put in for logging purposes), and that one is "free of conflicting characters", and I input it in the "col" variable on the debugging sidebar in VS Code, which results in a successful request.

I tried doing the for with the rows instead, and I got the same results.

Comment: @OmriShneor I think you'll need to get your own Bearer token by logging in at https://gorest.co.in/consumer/login, and I don't know if you can just use my sample data or you'll have to create your own users and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) returns rows of strings, so the strings each need to be converted to a Python object for the `json` keyword argument in [requests.request](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request).  We can use [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to deserialize a string.

```py
req_obj = json.loads(col)
r = requests.request("POST", url, headers = headers, json = req_obj)
```